# Create two subscenes in a single rgl window without using mfrow3d in R

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I want to create two subscenes in a single rgl window in R, one on the left and the other on the right. I do not want to use `mfrow3d` function since in my real code, subscenes will not be aligned in a single row or column. Here is my code:

```
library(rgl)

# Open 3D device
open3d()

# Set up first subscene on the left
par3d(windowRect = c(0, 0, 0.5, 1))
plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = "red", type = "s")

# Set up second subscene on the right
par3d(windowRect = c(0.5, 0, 1, 1))
plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = "blue", type = "s")
```

I should be seeing red spheres on the left subscene and blue spheres on the right subscene. But the above code only returned blue spheres. I can see the red spheres appearing but quickly replaced by the subscene for the blue spheres. I read the user manual for windowRect and noted that it is "A vector of four values indicating the left, top, right and bottom of the displayed window". I think my issue lies in the misspecified `windowRect`argument, but I am not sure how I should update it.

Another question is if it is possible to plot the subscene for the blue spheres in the top right corner (1/4 of the width and height of the red spheres subscene) of the subscene for the red spheres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `windowRect` setting is for the whole window.  You only have one subscene.  I don't think you've shown us your real code, because setting the windowRect to that size makes it too small to display anything.

To set up a subscene at an arbitrary location, use `newSubscene3d()` with the `newviewport` setting describing the location in pixels relative to the container.

For example, this plots them side-by-side:

```
library(rgl)

# Open 3D device
open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 550, 550))

toplevel <- subsceneInfo()$id

# Set up first subscene on the left
                           # left bottom width height
newSubscene3d(newviewport = c(0,  0,     250,  500))
plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = "red", type = "s")

# Go back to the top level
useSubscene3d(toplevel)

# Set up second subscene on the right
newSubscene3d(newviewport = c(250, 0, 250, 500))
plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = "blue", type = "s")
```

If you want the second one as part of the first one, skip the `useSubscene3d(toplevel)` call, and just set up the new one, which will be embedded within the previous one.